# circle drawing in openGL python using Midpoint Circle Drawing Algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, glut, pyopengl

I want to draw a circle in OpenGL using Midpoint Circle Drawing Algorithm. I have implemented in Python but can't understand why the circle is not drawn.

My program is as below:

```
class MidPoint(object):
    def iterate(self):
        glViewport(-250, -150, 250, 150)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluOrtho2D(-250.0, 250.0, -150.0, 150.0)
        glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()

    def showScreen(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glLoadIdentity()
        self.iterate()
        glColor3f(0.5, 1.0, 1.0)
        #self.draw_points(45,45)
        self.drawCircle(100)
        glutSwapBuffers()

    def drawCircle(self,r):
        x = r
        y = 0
        d = 1 - r
        self.draw8Way(x, y)
        while (y <= x):
            if (d < 0):
                d=d+(2 * y+3)
                y=y+1
            else:
                d=d+(2 * y-2 * x+5)
                x=x-1
                y=y+1
            print("x: ",x," y: ",y)
            self.draw8Way(x, y)

    def draw8Way(self,x,y):
        glPointSize(5)
        glBegin(GL_POINTS)
        glVertex2f(x, y)
        glVertex2f(y, x)
        glVertex2f(-x, y)
        glVertex2f(-y, x)
        glVertex2f(-x, -y)
        glVertex2f(-y, -x)

        glVertex2f(x, -y)
        glVertex2f(y, -x)
        glEnd()

    def main_function(self):
        glutInit()
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)
        glutInitWindowSize(700, 700) #window size
        #glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
        glutInitWindowPosition(100,100)
        wind = glutCreateWindow(b"OpenGL Coding Practice") #window name
        glutDisplayFunc(self.showScreen)
        glutMainLoop()

MidPoint().main_function()
```

Answer (score 2):

[`glViewport`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml) specifies the viewport in pixel. The first and second arguments specify the bottom left corner and the third and fourth arguments specify the width and height. This has nothing to do with the orthographic projection. Since the size of your window is 700x700, the correct viewport rectangle is (0, 0, 700, 700):

<s>`glViewport(-250, -150, 250, 150)`</s>

```py
glViewport(0, 0, 700, 700)
```

Note that your viewport specifies a rectangle that is completely outside the window, so you can't see the circle.